# How to get all fields of Workfront object in Postman?

Tags: workfront-api

I am getting only some fields while calling **Workfront** API through postman. how to get all the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all fields for a specific object, you can pass the parameter `?fields=*`. Note that this only pulls system fields but not custom fields, collections, or references.

Comment: okay got the answer attask/api/v9.0/portfolio/search?filters={"field":"value"}